# Factorization of polynomial in a complete field

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $k$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $|\cdot|$ an absolute value on it (either Archimedean or not). Let $L$ be the completion of $k$ with respect to this value, and take any irreducible polynomial $f(X)$ in $k[X]$.

> Is is true that $f(X)$ is still separable on $L[X]$, i.e. every irreducibile factor of $f(X)$ in $L[X]$ has multiplicity 1?

My guess is no, but I really have no clue on how to think about it.

Comment: What makes you think completions behave differently than arbitrary field extensions where questions of extensions are concerned?

Comment: To be really honest, I'm using this fact in some homework so my guess was actually a pessimistic one. What gives me trouble is the completion procedure, it is not as clear to me as algebraic field extension.

Comment: It is not an algebraic extension, but the nature of the extension is really irrelevant here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here’s the way to look at this problem. Consider your polynomial $f(X)\in k[X]$. It’s separable if and only if $f$ and $f'$ are relatively prime. But from the equation $Af+Bf'=1$, you see that $f$ and $f'$ remain relatively prime in no matter what extension field $K\supset k$ you look at.

Comment: Really clear, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In characteristic $0$, all irreducible polynomials are separable, meaning that their roots in a splitting field are all simple roots. From this description it is also clear that separable polynomials remain separable over extensions fields.

Comment: That was also my idea, but I wasn't sure at all wheter it was reasonable or I was missing something.

Comment: For me isn't clear at all how this applies to the question: for instance, $f$ could be reducible over $L$.

Comment: @user26857: Yes of course, that is what the answer is about. Since $f$ is irreducible over $k$, it has simple roots in a splitting field over$~k$ (my first sentence). But then it also has simple roots in any larger field, for instance in its splitting field over$~L$, so it is separable over$~L$ (my second sentence). For the different irreducible factors into which $f$ might split over $L$ this means that each is separable, and moreover among them they have no common roots. In particular those irreducible factors are distinct.